# tvOS AVPlayerViewController Subtitles

Tags: avplayer, tvos, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller

I am having an issue displaying subtitles for AVPlayerViewController.

I set

```
[_player setRequiresFullSubtitles:YES];
```

in my code where I create the AVPlayerViewController, but it still does not show.

Comment: have you checked if your video has srt files embedded into it?

Comment: The value of this properties simply "Determines whether the user is given the option to turn off subtitles" (from the header doc).